# C# how to use an string from an program in another

Tags: c#, string, methods, call

I am practicing some code.

i have this code

class Program

```
{

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        Program a = new Program();
        a.Alalao();
        Program b = new Program();
        b.Game();
    }
    public void Alalao()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello my dear. How would you like to be called?");
        string n1 = Console.ReadLine();
        // more code
    }
    public void Game()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a game where you have answer questions. For each correct answer 1 get an point and for each wrong answer you lose a point.");
        Console.WriteLine("You will start with 5 points. Consider it as a courtesy");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, are you ready start?", n1);
    }
}
```

How can i put the string n1 from Alalao() inside the last command Console.writeline in Game()

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple possible ways. One solution is to use arguments/return values.

This is what structural programming is all about, you divide a larger problem into smaller chunks (methods) but still, you communicate these chunks using parameters and return values.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Program a = new Program();
    var name = a.Alalao();
    Program b = new Program();
    b.Game(name);
}

public string Alalao()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello my dear. How would you like to be called?");
    string n1 = Console.ReadLine();
    // more code

    return n1;
}
public void Game(string n1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a game where you have answer questions. For each correct answer 1 get an point and for each wrong answer you lose a point.");
    Console.WriteLine("You will start with 5 points. Consider it as a courtesy");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, are you ready start?", n1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Return *n1* from Alalao and add it as a parameter to Game. Like so...

```
public string Alaloa () {
  // ...
  string n1 = Console.ReadLine();
  // ...
  return n1;
}

// ...

public void Game (string inString) {
  // ..
  Console.WriteLine("{0}, are you ready start?", inString);
}
```

You will need to then save the return value from Alaloa as a variable and add it to the invocation of Game in the main method, like so...

```
static void Main (string[] args) {
  Program a = new Program();
  string myString = a.Alaloa(); // Saving the string to a variable
  
  Program b = new Program();
  b.Game(myString);
}
```